# Google tag manager event tracking on Mobile phone

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, google-tag-manager

I am pretty new to Google tag manager. I am testing the gtm events on my hybrid mobile application. I am able to track the events on chrome bowser and see which events get triggered and which one I am missing.

Is it possible to track the events on mobile device(android and iOS) and how can I do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is official guide from Google.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ or
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/